# Chrome Vulnerabilities are detected in vulnerability scan even after upgraded with latest versions

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, vulnerability-management

Had few chrome vulnerabilities [CVE-2020-6420] detected by BI(Retina). Upgraded the affected machines to chrome version 84.0.4147.89. After re-scan still the same vulnerabilities are detected.

Anyone experienced it before ? please help to resolve

Comment: False positives are common in any VM scanner. You assess and accept the finding.

Comment: How You Checked Your Browser for vulnerabilities?

Comment: @FarihaKhan yes, that's what the OP said. They are using a vulnerability scanner...